# MiniProfiler - What's the impact in terms of Memory Consumption?

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

In terms of memory consumption, what is the impact of running Mini-Profiler?

Also, if we use the included ***SqlServerStorage*** provider are the profiling results also stored in memory?